# Create nuget package for updated files only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to create nuget package (.nupkg) for my project for octopus deployment process using nuget.exe command line.

I am using below command to create a nuget package:

```
nuget pack D:\Project\MySampleProject\MySampleProject.csproj
```

Now I need to create another package for same project (Not whole project but only for updated files).

For example, I've changed in one view file and one js file than the package should contain only 2 files rather than whole project. Is there any solution?

Comment: But then it wouldn't be a package? this isn't possible or a good idea. A package is supposed to contain everything required to deploy whatever your deploying.

Comment: why would you want the package to only contain the updated files? It should contain the whole deployment. You don't know if the end user is installing it for the first time, or not. If it's not the first time, even if you include all the files which haven't changed, they still haven't changed, so it's no problem to overwrite them in the end-user's project, since they are the same as what is there already. I don't really understand why you think you need this idea?

Comment: @Liam, I want the updated files only in the package, because sometimes we are only updating few files and if we create package of whole application, it would be a bigger file. So to reduce the size of the package, I need to create package of only updated files.

Comment: how big is this package, exactly? Generally for most developers, they have a reasonably good internet connection and the size of the download isn't an issue. Are you targeting people with a very slow download speed, or something?

Comment: @ADyson, yes, download speed is not an issue. Package is around 50 to 60 MB. But if there's a way to reduce the size of the package, it would be better.

Comment: The "nuget pack" command already compresses your files when building the package file, so I doubt it could be shrunk much further, if at all. But I would say that's not really an issue. Ok it's not small, but how often do people realistically download and upgrade? It's a one-off task, maybe you upgrade every few weeks - at most! That's assuming a new release is even available, and you actually want/need to upgrade. I think you're worrying about something which isn't very important.